# How to upload multiple files on an HTML form

Tags: html, post, file-upload

I would have thought this would be super easy to find an answer to on the interwebs but apparently not.

On an HTML page, I wish to allow a user to select multiple files and upload them to my server.  Specific context is that the user needs to choose a resume file and a cover page to apply for a job.

Important considerations:

- I'm not interested in an HTML5 or flash or tricky solution - just the basic question, is it possible with plain old HTML in a plain old browser.
- I am okay with having multiple upload fields and multiple buttons to choose each file.
- A single submit button needs to submit them both.
- Needs to support IE6.

Is this possible?  It seems very hard to find a straight answer.

For example would something like this work? (I grabbed it from somewhere on the net sorry if I have not credited the source)

```
<form action="/py/uploadfile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
    <label>upload file<input type="file" name="file[]" id="file1" /></label>
    <label>upload file<input type="file" name="file[]" id="file2" /></label>
    <label>upload file<input type="file" name="file[]" id="file3" /></label>
    <label><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" /></label>
</form>
```

thanks

Comment: If you're using PHP, files, regardless of their names, are stored in the [`$_FILES`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) array. (You access a particular file using `$_FILES["file_name"]`.) Therefore, you can just have a bunch of file inputs, regardless of their names or ID's, and you can `foreach` over the files anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add another `input[type="file"]`, and make sure it has a different name:

```
<form action="...">
    ...other fields...
    <input type="file" name="coverLetter" />
    <input type="file" name="resume" />
    ...other fields...
    <input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

A file upload field that accepts multiple values:

```
<input type="file" name="files" multiple>
```

This method works on most modern browsers, according to [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/mdn-html_elements_input_multiple).