# Amazon S3 browser upload - is it possible to upload multiple files?

Tags: post, file-upload, amazon-s3

Is it possible to upload multiple files direct to Amazon S3 from a browser using basically this  approach : [How to upload multiple files on an HTML form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924712/how-to-upload-multiple-files-on-an-html-form)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the simple answer is that this is not possible without JavaScript/Flash.